# Kinetic JS performance issue in Chrome & Opera

Tags: html, performance, browser, canvas, kineticjs

I have some heavy performance problem in my kinetic JS app when i use Chrome or Opera browser. When i use IE or Firefox the performance is fine. You can see app here http://kinlibtst.elitno.net/
js code here: http://kinlibtst.elitno.net/new.js

I'm using free hosting for now, can it be the reason? Maybe bad host parser?

Comment: I think it just stems from you having a lot of data on your page. There are a lot of images for the browser to parse.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a small problem, you have lots of things like this:

```
 cont_venes_sel.on('mouseout', function() {
      document.body.style.cursor = "default";
      this.transitionTo({  // <--- this is a small problem, not a big one
        opacity: 0,
        duration: 0.3
      })
      stage.draw();   //  <---- this is the big problem
    });
```

The question is, why are you redrawing the whole stage?
Try this:

```
   cont_venes_sel.on('mouseout', function() {
      document.body.style.cursor = "default";
      this.setOpacity(0);  // <--- much less memory required, less intense
      this.getParent().draw();   //  <---- this way you only redraw the layer
    });
```